# Editing Excel 365 by hand and reading with graph api latency

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, excel-365

I have an excel on line documents that can be edited by users in the Excel 365 web application.

I have an application that read this excel file with the graph api.

I have successfully managed to read the data from the file but when a user change the excel file and Excel says it has been saved, if I read the file immediately with my application I have old data.

I have to wait for 30s to have the updated data. Is there anything I can do to avoid this latency.

Here is my call to get the data :

```cs
var range = await _graphClient.Drives[_driveId].Items[_itemId].Workbook.Worksheets[workseetName]
            .Range(rangeAddress).UsedRange(true)
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Hi @juChom were you able find a workaround for this?

Comment: @sid I think that the issue is not related to Graph API. I see the same delay when I have the file on SharePoint/OneDrive. After editing the excel (in the browser/in desktop app) it takes sometimes several minutes until the modified date column is updated.

Comment: We have further identified that issue is related to sessions. If we immediately close the excel file after manually updating, we get the updated values from api.

Comment: I didn't have time to dig further

Answer (score 2):

I posted a similar question on the graph API github repo. They responded here:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-cli/issues/215#issuecomment-1379391739

They suggest using the etag property to determine whether the workbook has changed since that last access. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0

They also suggest using the Excel session. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0#sessions-and-persistence

However in my personal testing the session method didn't fix the delay in excel saving the data in the backend.

They also mentioned:
"I cannot guarantee that these will work. I don't think this API was designed with real-time co-authoring in mind."

Comment: Hi Owen were you able find a workaround for this?

Comment: Hey Sid, no workaround given on their side, a hack to get around this is to dedicate a cell with last update value and check that for every API update